# Where python keeps --prefix(sys.prefix) settings?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

So my question is about where is it?

And is where any way to change that?

Something goes wrong on my Windows 8 machine.

`PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib`

Output from python:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'C:\\Python27'
```

Same here:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"
C:\Python27
```

From ipython:

```
ipython -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"

Defaulting color scheme to 'NoColor'
c:\Python27 # low c
```

And finally I have trouble with `virtualenv`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 994, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1192, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1130, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1095, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename C:\Python27\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['c:\\python27']
```

Why they are different?

So fast solution is just to change `PYTHONPATH` with low 'c', it seems ugly.

Comment: They are all the same, except the error shows something is being matched case-insensitively.

Comment: Note that ``\\`` is just the string representation giving you properly escaped backslashes. Use `print sys.prefix` if you want to see the value without escaping.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it possible to avoid case mismatching?

Comment: You'll need to show us the full traceback, I don't know what code is throwing that exception.

Comment: And that `ipython` shows the path with a lowercase `c` is.. unexpected and a little weird. Not sure how that happened.

Comment: Huh, I've just noticed that in `traceback` a bunch of different cases..
I am using git bash and probably made some `pip install` thorugh it.

Comment: I do think virtualenv should be doing the check case-insensitively there (using [`os.path.normcase()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)). I'll see about filing a bug..

Comment: See https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/815